# highcharts inside datatables editor form? (Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts')

Tags: javascript, datatable, highcharts

[Datatables](https://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/index.html) editor has a (new/edit) form where I need to set up a highcharts chart, I've set up the div inside the form like this:

```
   <div id="graph"></div>
```

, loaded the highcharts's js files at the begining of the code and create thisfunction:

```
$(function () {
    $('#graph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });
});
```

and with all thi what I get is this:

```
    Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
```

Comment: You have included proper jquery and highchart libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Change `div` id to `container` like:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

or change `#container` in your code to `#graph` like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#graph').highcharts({
```

It seems that you did not include highchart libraries. Commenting out highcharts.js link I got  error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
```

Comment: Sorry my fault, both are the same "#graph"

Comment: You have included proper jquery and highchart libraries? With your code and included libraries I got line chart. See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/IcolAYIN/1/edit)

Comment: yup, it works but not inside datatables editor form, in your example you are not using it

Comment: Yes, that's true but somehow you have to include them. You have tab `Includes` and there you have to provide correct links.

Comment: "somehow" This is my question (:

Comment: I've never used that editor. But what I see there is `Includes`tab, there you provide your links. Example shows `css` at the beginning and at the end there are links for js libs. And there you put links for highcharts ...

Comment: I'm almost sure is a matter of where to include the highcharts files

Comment: Sure. highcharts.js should be after jquery.js. And your code after that. But I you do similar as in example, it did not work.